# The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am having a **Form** that has two **TextFormFields** and i am trying to validate the **TextFormFields** but i cam getting below error

```
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

The key [LabeledGlobalKey<FormState>#fb338] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were:
- _SingleChildViewport(renderObject: _RenderSingleChildViewport#51664)
- _SingleChildViewport(renderObject: _RenderSingleChildViewport#d9e77)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2868:13)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#2      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2815:20)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#4      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2811:36)
#5      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:6)
#6      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2935:11)
#7      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3016:8)
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:19)
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#16     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#17     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#18     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

Below is how my code looks like

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:blur/blur.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fullscreen/fullscreen.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController phoneNoController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pinController = TextEditingController();

  FocusNode phoneNoFocusNode = FocusNode();
  FocusNode pinFocusNode = FocusNode();

  int phoneMaxInputLength = 13;
  int pinMaxInputLength = 4;

  bool phoneNoHasFocus = false;
  bool pinNoHasFocus = false;
  bool showPhoneNoErrorSuffixIcon = false;
  bool showPinErrorSuffixIcon = false;

  bool enablePhoneNoAutoValidation = false;
  bool enablePinAutoValidation = false;

  bool obscurePin = true;

  late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset("videos/intro.mp4")
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        videoPlayerController.setVolume(0.2);
        videoPlayerController.setPlaybackSpeed(1);
        videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
        videoPlayerController.play();
        setState(() {});
      });

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);

    clearPrefs();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    phoneNoController.dispose();
    phoneNoFocusNode.dispose();
    pinController.dispose();
    pinFocusNode.dispose();
  }

  void clearPrefs() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
          ? Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController),
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 400,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Form(
                    key: loginFormKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 5),
                              child: Text(
                                "Sign In",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Config.boldTitleTextStyle,
                              )),
                          Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5, left: 5),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                onChanged: (phoneNo) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    enablePhoneNoAutoValidation = true;
                                  });
                                },
                                autovalidateMode: enablePhoneNoAutoValidation
                                    ? AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
                                    : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                                maxLength: phoneMaxInputLength,
                                focusNode: phoneNoFocusNode,
                                controller: phoneNoController,
                                cursorHeight: 20,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter Phone Number",
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                    suffixIcon: showPhoneNoErrorSuffixIcon
                                        ? Tooltip(
                                            message:
                                                "We require a phone number to be able to proceed",
                                            triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
                                            child: const Icon(
                                                Icons.error_outline_rounded,
                                                color: Colors.red),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                            ))
                                        : null),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                                ],
                                validator: (phoneNo) {
                                  if (phoneNo!.isEmpty) {
                                    phoneNoFocusNode.requestFocus();
                                    phoneNoHasFocus = true;

                                    WidgetsBinding.instance!
                                        .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        showPhoneNoErrorSuffixIcon = true;
                                      });
                                    });

                                    return "Please Enter Phone Number";
                                  } else {
                                    phoneNoHasFocus = false;

                                    WidgetsBinding.instance!
                                        .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        showPhoneNoErrorSuffixIcon = false;
                                      });
                                    });

                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              )),
                          Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5, left: 5),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                obscureText: obscurePin,
                                onChanged: (pin) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    enablePinAutoValidation = true;
                                  });
                                },
                                autovalidateMode: enablePinAutoValidation
                                    ? AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
                                    : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                                maxLength: pinMaxInputLength,
                                focusNode: pinFocusNode,
                                controller: pinController,
                                cursorHeight: 20,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Enter Pin",
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                    suffixIcon: showPinErrorSuffixIcon
                                        ? Tooltip(
                                            message:
                                                "We require a pin to be able to proceed",
                                            triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
                                            child: const Icon(
                                                Icons.error_outline_rounded,
                                                color: Colors.red),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                            ))
                                        : IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(
                                              obscurePin
                                                  ? Icons.visibility
                                                  : Icons.visibility_off,
                                            ),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                obscurePin = !obscurePin;
                                              });
                                            },
                                          )),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                                ],
                                validator: (pin) {
                                  if (pin!.isEmpty) {

                                    if (!phoneNoHasFocus){
                                      pinFocusNode.requestFocus();
                                    }

                                    pinNoHasFocus = true;

                                    WidgetsBinding.instance!
                                        .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        showPinErrorSuffixIcon = true;
                                      });
                                    });

                                    return "Please Enter Phone Number";
                                  } else {
                                    pinNoHasFocus = false;

                                    WidgetsBinding.instance!
                                        .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        showPinErrorSuffixIcon = false;
                                      });
                                    });

                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              )),
                          Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, bottom: 10, right: 5, left: 5),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                      Logger().i("FieldsAreEmpty${false}");
                                    } else {
                                      Logger().i("FieldsAreEmpty${true}");
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text("Proceed".toUpperCase()),
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                  ))),
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              ).frosted(
                blur: 10,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
              )
            ])
          : Container(),
    ));
  }
}
```

I have tried creating a `GlobalKey<FormState>()` for each **TextFormField** and assigning to the key of each **TextFormField** but its still bringing the error. I have also tried placing the Form outside the Container but its still bringing the error

Comment: Does this happen during debug?

Comment: yeah i haven't tested in release yet

Comment: This occurs all the time for me but only in debug mode

Comment: There must be possibly a way to get rid of the error right ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error in flutter 2.10. I `hot restart` the app. And I know this is not the best solution.